# extract a column from many files and paste together in a single file

Tags: python, linux, awk

I have a number of files (between 250-20000) which each include two columns with  header file.
I want to extract the second column from these files and paste them all together in a single file so I can analyze it.

```
#Frame      Dih_00000
       1     -92.6371
       2     -97.9913
       3     -91.1572
       4     -89.9374
       5     -91.8934
       6     -93.1060
       7     -93.4912
```

files look like this.
would you please help me how can I do this using awk or a python script.

Comment: you have to try do it by yourself firstly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{print $2}' dihed_*.dat > file.new
```

OR just use `cut` command

```
cut -d" " -f2 dihed_*.dat > file.new
```

**EDIT**

not know is it elegant solution or not but it fulfill your requirement.

```
tail -q -n +2  dihed_*.dat | awk '{print $2}' > file.new
```

And

```
tail -q -n +2  dihed_*.dat | cut -d" " -f2 > file.new
```

Comment: This is just the same as Dimitry posted, but not using `cat`

Comment: @Jotne apples and pears are two different things.

Comment: Thanks Jayesh.but the problem is I have many files each named dihed_1.dat to dihed_500.dat.how can I write a loop in awk so I can enter as many files as I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.in | awk {'print $2'} > file.out
```

get the second column and save it in the file.out

Comment: You should not use  `cat` with programs like `awk`.

Comment: @Jotne Why? Please clarify or just give me a link. Thank you

Comment: Do a google search.  `sed` `awk` can read files itself. Using `cat` makes it run slower and using more resources.  Also function in `awk` like `FILENAME` does not work.  And your single quote are wrong.  `awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry In particular, google "UUOC" which stands for "Useless Use Of Cat". It's a common enough problem that it has it's own abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do.

```
awk '$0=$2' files* > new_file
```

Comment: if I understand correctly this is just to extract the second column from one file and sent it to new file.what if there are 'n' number of input files(extract the second column from all append them and send to a single output file). Thanks

Comment: @amir That's why I did write `file*`. Lets say all your files starts with `2014_`.  Then use `2014_*` and all this file will be selected and we get column #2 from all of them into `new_file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ a[FNR] = (FNR in a ? a[FNR] OFS : "") $2 } END{ for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i] }' file1 file2 ...
```

The above assumes all of your files have the same number of lines. If that is not the case, tell us about it and update your question to post some more representative sample input (e.g. 3 small files of different lengths) and expected output.